# Firebase authentication using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

So far I was working with Mongodb and Express. There my whole authentication was done by checking `req.user` object. From what I saw, Firebase authentication is mostly done in the front end. How can I get `req.user` to work with Firebase in the back end? I saw a couple of [tutorials](https://youtu.be/KdLDIob_WDM?list=PLJm7_t7JnSjn__VC3sK86o2YlUuwlPKkO), but they just showed a couple of methods and went on. I mean to ask more about the logic, but some code examples would probably help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Firebase authentication is mostly done in the front end

Correct. User auth is entirely done client-side when using the provided SDKs from Firebase.

However, if you need to do some special auth, such as integrating with LDAP/AD or some other enterprise shenanigans, then you would need to do [custom token creation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/#custom_token_creation) that client-side SDKs would use to authenticate the user.

> How can I get `req.user` to work with Firebase in the back end?

This is something **you** will need to implement yourself. The flow client-side would go something like:

1. User performs auth client-side.

   - Firebase will set auth state in `localstorage` by default. See [Authentication State Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)
2. When a user attempts to access your Express API, you will need to retrieve the token from `localstorage` and send it with your API request.

Let's assume you attach the token on the request header: `FIREBASE_AUTH_TOKEN: abc`. See [Firebase retrieve the user data stored in local storage as firebase:authUser:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035594/firebase-retrieve-the-user-data-stored-in-local-storage-as-firebaseauthuser/44078288#44078288)

So on the server side, using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), you will retrieve that token and verify it via [`verifyIdToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#verifyIdToken). Quick dirty example below of middleware:

```
const {auth} = require('firebase-admin');
const authService = auth();

exports.requiresAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
    const idToken = req.header('FIREBASE_AUTH_TOKEN');

    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.DecodedIdToken
    let decodedIdToken;

    try {
        decodedIdToken = await authService.verifyIdToken(idToken);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
        return;
    }

    req.user = decodedIdToken;
    next();
}
```

You would then use this middleware like so:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {requiresLogin} = require('./my-middleware.js');

router.get('/example', requiresLogin, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user)
})
```

I hope this gives you an idea of what to do. I haven't worked with Firebase for a while and the information above is what I gathered from looking at the documentation.

Comment: Ok. It seems like it's gonna be easier to use localstorage as intended by the creators. Thanks for all the work anyway!

Comment: Just a random thought. Since from what I can see Firebase is doing almost everything on the front-end, wouldn't it be better to use it with Angular?

Comment: "Better" is subjective. You use whatever tool **you** need to get the job done.

Comment: @AlexIronside you realise that if you do this kind of stuff on the client side you have serious security issues in your app.

Comment: I ended up using React and checking the user by `firebase.auth()`

Comment: Right, but my above answer still stands. You've successfully authenticated a user client side, but you still need to make sure the user is authorized to access your Express server.

Comment: Excellent answer, exactly the direction I was looking for.

Comment: are there any performance implications or limitations to keep in mind when calling verifyIdToken() on every request? very good answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to have server side sessions only, you should consider using Firebase session cookies: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions.

An example is available to show how to use `httpOnly` cookies at: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/tree/master/auth-sessions